# Change of key ordering in python dictionary when sending to engines

Tags: python, dictionary, parallel-processing

I wanted to send a dictionary to my set of engines in parallel python (ipython).

```
from IPython.parallel import Client, interactive
rc = Client()
dv = rc[:]
dv.push(dict(mydict = mydict))
```

Amazingly, keys are not ordered the same way (all engines dict are, but this order is different from the master). Any simple way to correct this? (OrderedDict seem quite restrictive to me and I am not sure it would be relevant)

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries are not ordered.  If you want them to be, you must either use an OrderedDict or simply do `sorted(mydict)` to sort the keys when needed.

Comment: I know they are not ordered, but the order is not random and does not change as long as the dictionary is not modified (obviously). I am sending the dictionary to engines and would have expected the order to be kept (order is the same in all engines).

Comment: They are not ordered.  They have no ordering.  Do not expect ordering from an unordered container.   Not the "same" order, not ascending or descending.  No order.

Comment: then why, when defining two dictionaries with the same keys, iterating through the keys will be the same? Isn't this the exact definition of order?

Comment: There are no guarantees about the ordering.  Including, no guarantee that the ordering will differ.  I hope you get my point now, as I will not entertain further inquiries here as to why dictionaries are ordered in certain ways.  They are unordered.

Comment: Ok I got it thanks, same "order" should be treated as a mere coincidence/irrelevant.